# How to get an AudioUnit property value in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, audiounit

I'm working on an audio debug feature and trying to get the  `AudioUnit.AudioUnitPropertyIDType.Latency` property value of my audio unit using Xamarin.iOS. Unfortunately I don't see related method to retrieve the value property value like `audioUnit.GetParameter`.

Though I can see and successfully set properties using `audioUnit.SetParameter` method.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but AudioUnit has private AudioUnitSetProperty method which is exposed as SetAudioFormat, SetCurrentDevice and a number of other methods, but not for Latency. Looks like it wasn't implemented by Xamarin. But you always can use reflection ;)

```
public void SetAudioFormat(AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat, AudioUnitScopeType scope, uint audioUnitElement = 0U)
{
  int k = AudioUnit.AudioUnitSetProperty(this.handle, AudioUnitPropertyIDType.StreamFormat, scope, audioUnitElement, ref audioFormat, (uint) Marshal.SizeOf<AudioStreamBasicDescription>(audioFormat));
  if (k != 0)
    throw new AudioUnitException(k);
}
```